# Stream of String Array to a Json or Hashmap

Tags: java, json, java-stream, reactive-programming

I have a stream of string arrays and each has a length of two. I would like to convert it into a json after the stream . The first element in the string array is a sort of a key and the second one of its possible values. How can I covert it ?

Input Stream: [c1 , 1234] , [c1, 3434] , [c2 , 887],[c1 , 52] , [c1 , 372],[c2 ,7292], [c3 , 302]..

Output

```
   {
     "c1" : [1234, 3434, 52,372],
     "c2" : [887, 7292]
     "c3" : [302]
}
```

Comment: that's a map of string keys and array/list values. You just need to figure how to do the mapping

Answer (score 1):

It makes most sense to do it like this:

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.add(new String[] { "c1", "1234" });
list.add(new String[] { "c1", "3434" });
list.add(new String[] { "c2", "887" });
list.add(new String[] { "c1", "52" });
list.add(new String[] { "c1", "372" });
list.add(new String[] { "c2", "7292" });
list.add(new String[] { "c2", "302" });

Map<String, Set<String>> map = list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(t -> t[0], t -> new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { t[1] })), (t, u) -> {
            t.addAll(u);
            return t;
        }));
```

But I'm a bit obsessive about one-liners, so I like to do it like this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t[0],
                        t -> (Set<String>) new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { t[1] })),
                        (t, u) -> Stream.concat(t.stream(), u.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

Either way, this is the output:

```
{
  "c1": [
    "1234",
    "3434",
    "52",
    "372"
  ],
  "c2": [
    "302",
    "887",
    "7292"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It could be made shorter with groupingBy: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t-> t[0], Collectors.mapping(v -> v[1], Collectors.toSet())))`  :)

Comment: I had a followup question...we use list.stream().collect() here.  But Collect  stops  the  stream right ? Is there a way in which  as the stream flows put the values it into the  corresponding buckets  and  then collect  it . Am I wrong somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

- split the string int `Cn ###` pairs
- and convert  to a map using `Cn` as the key and a list of `###` as the value.

```
String str =
        "[c1 , 1234] , [c1, 3434] , [c2 , 887],[c1 , 52] , [c1 , 372],[c2 ,7292], [c3 , 302]";
String[] arr = str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\s]", "").split(",");

Map<String, List<Integer>> map = 
       IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < arr.length, i -> i + 2)
             .mapToObj(i -> new String[] { arr[i], arr[i + 1] })
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
                  TreeMap::new,
                  Collectors.mapping(
                        a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1]),
                        Collectors.toList())));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{\n");
map.forEach((k, v) -> sb.append(
        "  \"" + k + "\"" + " : " + v.toString() + ",\n"));
int comma = sb.lastIndexOf(",");
sb.replace(comma, comma + 1, "\n}");

System.out.println(sb);
```

Prints

```
{
  "c1" : [1234, 3434, 52, 372],
  "c2" : [887, 7292],
  "c3" : [302]
}
```

Comment: This would work perfectly if I didn't have the for loop but a  stream